# Remove duplicate words/string from a tab separated file

Tags: linux, sed, awk

I want to remove duplicate words/strings from a large tab separated file using Linux commands.

```
names            john, cnn, mac, tommy, mac, patrick, ngc, discovery, john, cnn, adam, patrick
cities            san jose, santa clara, san franscisco, new york, san jose, santa clara
```

The above is the file format, I want to retain the tabs and commas after removing the duplicate words.

```
names            john, cnn, mac, tommy, patrick, ngc, discovery, adam
cities            san jose, santa clara, san franscisco, new york
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: No, but the tabs and commas are important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk 'BEGIN {
         FS = ", |\t"
     }
     {
          printf "%s\t", $1
          delim = ""
          for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) {
              if (! ($i in seen)) {
                  printf "%s%s", delim, $i
                  delim = ", "
              }
              seen[$i]
          }
          printf "\n"
          delete seen
     }' inputfile
```

If you're not using GNU AWK (`gawk`) then you can't `delete` the array, use `split("", array)` instead.

Comment: Thank you so much Dennis. Your script worked like a charm! But in the output tabs are gone, and I get a comma with space.

names    , john, cnn, mac, tommy, patrick, ngc, discovery, adam

Comment: @Kaartz: That's odd. It works correctly for me. Double check to make sure the input file has tabs. Also, make sure you're using the current version of the script from my answer. I quickly added the `delim` feature after posting the first version without it. What version of AWK are you using? What OS/distribution?

Comment: I fixed it by adding printf "%s\t\t\t\t", $1. Thank you so much for this script.

Answer (score 2):

`sed` and `awk` by themselves aren't particularly well suited for this. `uniq` is better.

First pull out the names into another file, say `names`. You can use sed for this:

```
head -1 inputfile | sed 's/^names\s*//g' > names
```

So now names contains `john, cnn, mac, tommy, mac, patrick, ngc, discovery, john, cnn, adam, patrick`.

Then use this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS=","}{print $0}' names | sort | uniq | awk 'BEGIN{ORS=","}{print $0}'
```

Output is `adam,cnn,discovery,john,mac,ngc,patrick,tommy,`. You can remove the last comma also if you want using `sed`. Of course you can pipe the output of the `head` command to the second `awk` also. In that case, you won't need the intermediate `names` file.

Same for cities. I am assuming order is not important for you.

Comment: `sort | uniq` can be replaced by `sort -u` on most linux boxes. I don't know how portable across Unix this is, it works on my Solaris box.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
sed -i ':a;s/\(\(\<[^,]*\),.*\)\( \2,*\)/\1/;ta;s/,$//' /tmp/a
```